# "Element Not Interactable" Error using Selenium on a clickable object

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to using Selenium with Python. I'm trying to click on this sign-in button on glassdoor: [Glassdoor Sign-in Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcKOp.png)

Actual: Using both the XPATH and the classname "LockedHomeHeaderStyles__signInButton", I keep getting the "ElementNotInteractableException" thrown.

Expected: I should be able to select the element and click it.

When I open the site and try to manually click the button myself, I am able to do this. Am I doing something wrong in my code?

```
def sign_in():
sign_in_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "LockedHomeHeaderStyles__signInButton"))
)
sign_in_element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two button element with "Sign In" text. You need second one. Try using the below `xpath`-

```
//button[text()="Sign In" and not(contains(@class,"d-flex"))]
```